# Weblogic 12c - Suddenly JMS Server stopped processing messages

Tags: server, jms, weblogic

Team,
We are facing a strange issue in our webservice application.
It has 6 weblogic managed instances (4 # m01,m02,m04,m05 - handles webservice requests which post the messages to JMS queues, 2 # m03,m06 - JMS instances which have MDB components which actually process the messages from queue).

We have observed one of the JMS instance (M06) is stopped processing messages all of sudden without any errors in the application or server logs. We observed the connection factory is not responding. This also causing hogging threads in service instances while posting the and searching the messages from the JMS queues. We are not able to see any issue from the  thread dumps as well.

Adding to this when we try to stop the M06 instance it is not going down, eventually we had to kill the instance process and start the instance to resolve the issue. Then it is working fine for few days then again issue resurfacing.

We are using weblogic 12c.

Any one had faced this kind of issue earlier. Or any one have any idea what could have went wrong. Your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'll be you, I'll start by creating error queue, to get rid of any "poisoned" messages. More information can be found here: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4670. Then try to check error queue and message content there.

Secondly, try to turn off mentioned instance (M06) at all, if bottleneck/errors does not appear on some other node, check M06 instance configuration and compare it with other nodes -> issue will be definitely somewhere there.

Comment: Thank you Lubomir for your inputs. We try these options.